# Converting checkbox checked property to anchor tag clicked property

Tags: angular

In my HTML I have a check box which when checked, a variable in .ts file will be set true and when unchecked it will be false.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-all" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="chkAll" />
  
  <label class="k-multiselect-checkbox k-checkbox-label k-value-list-checkall " for="chk-all">
    Check All
  </label>
```

Here, I need to convert this check box to two anchor tags respectively Check all and Uncheck all

```
<a id="chk-all" class="k-checkbox" [clicked]="chkAll" />
  
  <label class="k-multiselect-checkbox k-checkbox-label k-value-list-checkall " for="chk-all">
    Check All
  </label>

<a id="unchk-all" class="k-checkbox" [clicked]="chkAll" />
  
  <label class="k-multiselect-checkbox k-checkbox-label k-value-list-checkall " for="unchk-all">
    Uncheck All
  </label>
```

How, can I make this work to when clicking on Check All link, I want make chkAll true and when clicking on Uncheck All link, I want to make it false. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (click) event handler. You could also use this directly on the label if desired.

`<a id="unchk-all" class="k-checkbox" (click)="chkAll = false" />`

`<a id="chk-all" class="k-checkbox" (click)="chkAll = true" />`